# progress bar in quiz app

Tags: python, django

I want to customise this quiz app:

https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz

Implementing a progress bar to help the user understand his advance in the quiz.
But I'm not sure what is the easiest way to do this with this bootstrap code in the template:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is this view on views.py:

```
def user_new_quiz_session(request, quiz):
    """
    initialise the Sitting class
    """
    sitting = Sitting.objects.new_sitting(request.user, quiz)



    if 'page_count' not in request.session:
        request.session['page_count'] = int(0)  #  session page count for adverts

    return user_load_next_question(request, sitting, quiz)
```

If I use the count method in questions, it will just be shown in the first page. But I would like to have a progress bar in entire quiz.
How should I do this?

Comment: How the rest of the questions/pages are loaded? via ajax?

Comment: One question is loaded each time, it's a django view that controls it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only had a brief look at your source code, so these are some thoughts on a way to approach this problem, though not a complete solution.

You could try to add a field/method to the `Sitting` model that calculates the number of questions for the sitting.

Then in the views in `user_load_next_question` you can calculate the progress by dividing the `page_count` by the number of questions which you can now access via the sitting object. Some simple number and string manipulations will get you the numbers you want in the template for calculating the progress percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the quiz app.

There are a few different ways you could approach this. Like Tbrisker says, you could modify the `Sitting` model. It has this field:

```
    question_list = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=1024)
```

You could could the length at the start of a quiz to use as a tracking variable.

As also mentioned, the original version of the quiz app had the session variable `request.session['page_count']`

That was increased with each answered question but was not reset in between quizzes.

I have added the idea of a progress bar to the "To Do" list for the quiz app. Keep an eye on it and I should hopefully have implemented it shortly.

https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz